# How to create an index for exact string search in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I use PostgreSQL 14, and I have a table responsible for storing all session IDs that are created for users of an account.

As a user can do many logins, over a long period there can be thousands of records for a single user.

However, it is necessary in an interval of time to update this record and for that I do a search for the user ID, user Account and the session ID.

As there is no index for the SID, it uses an index based only on the user and account ID, but this type of query in some cases has a running time of 17ms to perform an update, with an average of 4.5ms. What I consider a reasonably high time.

I've tried to create a `BTREE` index using the User ID, Account ID and SID, but PostgreSQL doesn't use it, preferring to do a filter to remove more than 3K rows from the results.

Am I doing something wrong in creating my index or is this really a decision by PostgreSQL that it thought it better to use another index?

**OLDER INDEX AND USED BY POSTGRESQL PLANNER**

```
CREATE INDEX idx_user_accesslog_operator_id 
   ON public.user_accesslog USING btree (operator_id, account_id);
```

**INDEX**

```
CREATE INDEX idx_user_accesslog_sid 
  ON public.user_accesslog USING btree (operator_id, account_id, sid);
```

**ANALYZE**

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
UPDATE user_accesslog 
  SET last_connection = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
WHERE operator_id = 9999 
  AND account_id = 123 
  AND sid = 'gQ7RVG15ukzDN08R5bsuewNdjLNvNUv90XhvU6MFRUT=';
```

**RESULT**

```
Update on user_accesslog  (cost=0.43..2.66 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=4.541..4.542 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using idx_user_accesslog_operator_id on user_accesslog  (cost=0.43..2.66 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=4.540..4.540 rows=0 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((operator_id = 9999) AND (account_id = 123))
"        Filter: ((sid)::text = 'gQ7RVG15ukzDN08R5bsuewNdjLNvNUv90XhvU6MFRUT='::text)"
        Rows Removed by Filter: 3216
Planning Time: 0.069 ms
Execution Time: 4.561 ms
```

Comment: Did you try an index where `sid` is the leading column?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Similar to this one?
`CREATE INDEX idx_user_accesslog_sid ON public.user_accesslog USING btree (sid, account_id, operator_id);`

Comment: "*an average of 4.5ms. What I consider a reasonably high time*" - What's consider a fast runtime to you then?...for some < 1s is a feat, for most < 1ms is definitely a feat. Are you running this update 200+ times per second (on average)?

Comment: What execution plan do you get if you drop the index that is currently used?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe To perform this test I would have to wait for a time when the app is not used so much. As it is already in production, this will generate a lot of problems as there are a lot of requests for it per second.

Comment: @J.D. 
I would say that this request is executed a lot per second, at an average of 250 req/s.

Comment: @Tom "To perform this test I would have to wait for a time when the app is not used"  That is why we have test servers.

Comment: Presumably PostgreSQL doesn't know it will need to filter that many rows.  The number of rows expected to be filtered is (unfortunately) not one of the things reported by EXPLAIN.  To get that value, you would do a different query `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM user_accesslog WHERE operator_id = 9999 AND account_id = 123`;

Comment: So you're averaging about 1.1s of update time per second. Sounds like a process optimization should be in order, not sure why so many updates per second for the aforementioned use case.

Comment: @J.D. Our app has a function that allows the user to terminate sessions that are logged in and had the last update less than 7 days ago. That's why every 5 minutes the system executes an individual update for each user, saying that their session was active at that moment. In this case, as there are several users, there are many requests per second.